# nginx virtual conf + qwebirc + proxy_pass + index.html

Tags: html, nginx

Could you please help me to achieve the following

I want http://bla.domain.com to point to the link below.

```
http://bla.example.com:4321/?nick=Nick.....&amp&channels=Bulgaria%2CSofia%2Csex%2C30-40&prompt=1&uio=OD1mYWxzZSY5PXRydWUmMTI9dHJ1ZQf0&amp;prompt=1
```

I have followed the original nginx stuff --> https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/qwebirc/

In the moment the index.html was not presented as i want it

So another and better solution will be when someone open bla.example.com to open the hole link (http://bla.example.com:4321/?nick=Nick.....&amp&channels=Bulgaria%2CSofia%2Csex%2C30-40&prompt=1&uio=OD1mYWxzZSY5PXRydWUmMTI9dHJ1ZQf0&prompt=1) but i don't want tho hole link be presented because is hard to remember.

You can check below the conf i have made till now.

```
server { server_name bla.example.com;

   location / {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            root /home/user/qwebirc/;
            index index.html;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;
   }

    #location / {
    #        autoindex on;
    #        autoindex_exact_size off;
    #        root /home/user/qwebirc/;
    #        index index.html;
    #        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    #}

    #location @proxy {
    #        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #        proxy_buffering off;
    #        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;
    #}

    location ~* \.php$ {
        #include fastcgi.conf # I include this in http context, it's just here to show it's required for fastcgi!
        try_files $uri =404; # This is not needed if you have cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0 in php.ini (you should!)
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

   ### Logs ###
   access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

}
```

Please bear in mind that i have tried to run it with the comment stuff instead of the working now.

Also here below is the index.html located in /home/user/qwebirc/

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
      html body {width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;font-family: arial;font-size: 10px;color: #6e6e6e;background-color: #000;} #preview-frame {width: 100%;background-color: #fff;}</style>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var calcHeight = function() {
           $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
         }

         $(document).ready(function() {
           calcHeight();
         });

         $(window).resize(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }).load(function() {
           calcHeight();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://bla.example.com/?nick=Nick.....&amp&channels=Bulgaria%2CSofia%2Csex%2C30-40&prompt=1&uio=OD1mYWxzZSY5PXRydWUmMTI9dHJ1ZQf0&amp;prompt=1" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a query string to the root URI and passing it through to the proxy. It may be easiest to split the proxy into two [`location` blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), one for the root URI and one for all other URIs. The common `proxy` statements can be moved into the outer block and inherited by both.

```
server { 
    server_name bla.example.com;

    root /home/kiril/qwebirc;
    index index.html;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:4321/?nick=Nick.....&amp&channels=Bulgaria%2CSofia%2Csex%2C30-40&prompt=1&uio=OD1mYWxzZSY5PXRydWUmMTI9dHJ1ZQf0&amp;prompt=1";
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/bla.example.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/bla.example.com.error.log;
}
```

The `proxy_pass` value is enclosed in quotes as it contains an embedded `;`.

Comment: Well, I test it in the scenario above, Syntax is okay but the goal it's not achieved. So location = / seems not working. Basically it's the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

So the current config is looking like this and not working. I can not start nginx.

```
server { server_name bla.example.com;

   location / {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            root /home/kiril/qwebirc/;
            index index.html;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_buffering off;
            #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;
   }

   location = / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:4321/?nick=Nick.....&amp&channels=Bulgaria%2CSofia%2Csex%2C30-40&prompt=1&uio=OD1mYWxzZSY5PXRydWUmMTI9dHJ1ZQf0&amp;prompt=1";
   }

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;
   }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        #include fastcgi.conf # I include this in http context, it's just here to show it's required for fastcgi!
        try_files $uri =404; # This is not needed if you have cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0 in php.ini (you should!)
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

   ### Logs ###
   access_log /var/log/nginx/bla.example.com.access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/bla.example.com.error.log;

}
```

With uncomment `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321;` in the above location / and remove it below it's working but it's the same. It still can not achieve what is required.

Comment: The configuration will not load because there are two `location /` blocks, which is an error. See the error log, or test the configuration with `nginx -t`. I have updated my answer to show the context of the outer block.